# Let V be an n-dimensional vector space over the field F and let T be a linear operator on V

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Let V be an n-dimensional vector space over the field F and let T be a linear operator on V such that the range and null space of T are identical. Prove that n is even. Give an example of such linear operator.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?  Where did you encounter this problem?  Please try to [provide some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/81360).

Answer (score 1):

Rank-Nulity theorem says that the dimension of the kernel + dimension of the image equals n.

An example:

$\begin {bmatrix} 1&1\\-1&-1 \end{bmatrix}$